# x:Uid generator for Windows 8 projects

Tags: windows, xaml, localization, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Multilingual App Toolkit by Microsoft is a quite good localization toolkit for Windows 8 (WinRT). The problem with MAT is that you need to put a special x:Uid attribute in any control you would like to be localized in all XAML files of your project.

Does anybody know some utility that allows to add x:Uid to XAML elements automatically?

Comment: Did this applocalizer work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://devtools.korzh.com/applocalizer. It's declared as free.
The tool itself is aimed for .NET applications localization. But it contains a wizard that does the job.
You just need to add your WinRT project (File -> New Project) and select "File -> Generate x:Uid's" menu item. Then follow the instructions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should describe why and how the tool behind the link could help the poster. Placing the link alone is not welcome in SO community.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Eugene. I see, brevity is not always a plus :) I edited the answer to be more adequate.

Comment: Unfortunately, the project is now discontinued.